# user permission to access media in android studio

Tags: android

creating this app in android studio using java language, it is kind of Instagram clone, for posting pictures i have this specific post activity in which i am trying to implement accessing the gallery of user to select a image but i am unable to do so... i was following a tutorial on youtube but its kind of old one so, few of the functions n all are deprecated so, i have tried many things but not able to solve my error. Also there are few functions which are deprecated such as 'continuationWithTask' for which i am not able to find alternatives

i followed this documentation on accessing user permission using media store permissions i did that too but ig im doing something wrong which i am not able to figure out

so here are my manifest permission and my code of post activity

-> manifest permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />
```

-> java code

```
private void openFileChooser() {
    mImage = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.GetContent(),
            o -> {
                    imageAdded.setImageURI(o);
                    imageUri = o;
            }
    );
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK
            && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        imageUri = data.getData();
        imageAdded.setImageURI(imageUri);
    }
}
```

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />

Comment: You do not need any permission to use GetContent() or ACTION_PICK_IMAGES. Remove all your permission code first. Then use only GetContent() or ACTION_PICK_IMAGES. Not both.

Comment: i tried ur suggestion and i got this error:-
java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleOwner com.example.lively.PostActivity@ceac9fd is attempting to register while current state is RESUMED. LifecycleOwners must call register before they are STARTED.
code:-
private void openFileChooser() {
        mImage = registerForActivityResult(
                new ActivityResultContracts.GetContent(),
                o -> imageAdded.setImageURI(o)
        );

        mImage.launch("image/*");  
    }
and in onCreate() im calling: 
imageAdded.setOnClickListener(v -> openFileChooser());

Comment: I did not read your comment as it was clear that it contained code. Dont put code in comments as it is unreadable. Put all code in your post..

Comment: appologies, i have updated the post, kindly look into it sir

Comment: solved the error by initializing mImage var in onCreate() and in openFileChooser() just called mImage.launch(), now on clicking mImage it opens gallery and we can select the picture but it still says 'no image selected'... rest is yet to be figured out

Comment: also we have to initialize the imageUri in onCreate() and change the rules of firebase database so that, user can upload image and it can be saved the firebase database.

Comment: Remove all code and imports. Only leave the two functions openFileChooser() and onActivityResult(). And the error message.